# How to declare a list so it contains a generic class no matter the generic type?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am looking for a way to declare a ***List*** that can contain any **generic class** instances, no matter the **generic type** of these instances. Perhaps a way to declare the List without having to specify the generic type of the class ?

```
public class Character {}
public class Hero : Character {}
public class Creature : Character {}

public abstract class ActorController<T> where T : Character
{
        protected T actor;
}
public class CharacterController : ActorController<Character> {}
public class HeroController : ActorController<Hero> {}
public class CreatureController : ActorController<Creature> {}

public class Zone
{
        // If it is even possible, what should I put instead of the ???
        // so the List understands that the generic type doesn't matter
        // and that I want any type of ActorController in it ?
        private List<ActorController<???>> actorControllers;
}
```

I specify that I am trying to avoid declaring a regular class or interface that would serve as a parent of ***ActorController***, as I would loose the interest of having a **dynamic ***Actor*** property** by doing so.

Thank you by advance, and sorry if I am misusing the jargon.

Comment: Have `ActorController` implement a common interface or inherit from a common base class.

Comment: @Llama That is what I am avoiding, as I will not be able to define a dynamic T Actor property in a base class/interface (that is what I am was doing so far).

Comment: @McGregor777 you can pass there a BaseClass - Character, as any of the subclasses extends it, calling function foo() in the interface would call the corresponding foo() in Hero or Creature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a covariant interface for it:

```
public interface IActorController<out T> where T : Character {
}
```

Then have `ActorController<T>` implement that interface:

```
public abstract class ActorController<T> : IActorController<T> where T : Character
{
  protected T actor;
}
```

Then you can make your list be of type `List<IActorController<Character>>`, and you can add any type to it:

```
public class Zone
{
  public List<IActorController<Character>> actorControllers;
}
/* ... */

var heroController = new HeroController();
var creatureController = new CreatureController();

myZone.actorControllers.Add(heroController);
myZone.actorControllers.Add(creatureController);
```

You just need to make sure anything you want to use on the list members is in the interface (or cast it)

Simple proof (based on your code, a bit modified to show some result): https://dotnetfiddle.net/KY2pMP (*updated to also show correct `Character` inheritance*)

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to do the trick so far ! I wasn't aware of covariant, I guess the "out" keyword is what's doing the magic there. I will take a look at it, but thank you again for putting me on the track :)

Comment: @McGregor777 yes, `out` means it's covariant, (`in` would mean it's contravariant). Notice that in C# covariance/contravariance only works on interfaces (not on classes), that's why you need to implement an interface for it. More info:; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Comment: I was using an interface for the sake of putting all my controllers in the same list (List<IController>), but as Actor wasn't contained in my interface, and making it generic to have a dynamic Actor was just displacing the issue, I was really in need of this solution.